# Change to home directory in PowerShell

Tags: windows-7, powershell

At the cmd command prompt, this command will take me to my home directory:

```
cd %UserProfile%
```

At the PowerShell command prompt, the same command produces this error:

```
Set-Location : Cannot find path 'C:\%UserProfile%' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:3
+ cd <<<<  %UserProfile%
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\%UserProfile%:String) [Set-Location], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetLocationCommand
```

What is the equivalent command in PowerShell?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can get to your home dir with this command:

```
cd $home
```

Comment: As an add-on to this answer, %UserProfile% does not literally translate to $home, and, instead, you should use the $env:UserProfile variable.

Comment: check out below answer https://superuser.com/a/858790/36875
Use "~" instead and save some chars!!

Answer (score 17):

This shorthand is one of my favorites:

```
cd ~
```

You can also do:

```
cd ~\Deskt
```

(Hit the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to auto-complete, it works nicely when you are buried in some deep directory and need to copy something to Desktop or somewhere in your $HOME)

Comment: Nice, somehow I didn't know you could use `~` in PowerShell!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. Devs are lazy and prefer to type 1 char instead of 5 :)

Comment: @thiago, but ~ is a special key, you need the Altgr on a german key layout. I wonder why this does not work: `function cd { Set-Location cd ~}` which is the linux style: `cd`only brings you home. My solution is to have another functionname such as:`function ho { Set-Location cd ~}` for home sweet home.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell, you can't use %userprofile% or %homepath%. You have to use $home to change directory to home path of current user.

```
cd $home
```

Comment: Someone already posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Adding a solution for those wanting a Linux-like experience**

When using a shell such as Bash, simply typing `cd` without parameters will take you to your home directory. To recreate this functionality in Powershell, add this to your profile:

```
function ChangeDirectory {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        $path
    )
    if ( $PSBoundParameters.ContainsKey('path') ) {
        Set-Location $path
    } else {
        Set-Location $home
    }
}
Remove-Item alias:\cd
New-Alias cd ChangeDirectory
```