# Editing an RDP session with Notepad and Powershell

Tags: remote-desktop, powershell-5.0

This worked for me:

```
ls "~\desktop\CMR Desktop.rdp" -recurse | %{ (gc $_ ) -replace "session bpp:i:32", "session bpp:i:24" | set-content $_.FullName -force }
```

Instead of the `-replace` switch, which one do I use to add or insert new lines to the config file?

Such as:

```
ls "~\desktop\CMR Desktop.rdp" -recurse | %{
     (gc $_ ) -insert "set audioqualitymode:1:2" |
     set-content $_.FullName -force
}
```

The `-insert` or `-add` doesn't work.

Comment: Okay with this article 
https://superuser.com/questions/446211/change-to-home-directory-in-powershell?newreg=22b2fcebb4cf4bfaba791fbe904507b4
i got the error to go away but it doesn't change the displayconectionbar:i:1 to a 0

Comment: What are you asking? Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1383609/edit) the question to make it more clear... in it's current state this question is likely to be closed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurse and looping is redundant as there are no sub folders under a file:

```
ls "~\desktop\CMR Desktop.rdp" | %{ "set audioqualitymode:1:2" | Out-File $_.FullName -append }
```

or even easier:

```
"set audioqualitymode:1:2" | Out-File (ls "~\desktop\CMR Desktop.rdp") -append
```

You need to use `append`.  `Set-Content` or using `Out-File` without the `append` parameter will completely overwrite the file with JUST the text in the quotes.

Comment: It did add the content i wanted but i put looks like this
s e t   a u d i o q u a l i t y m o d e : 1 : 2 
I don't know if that will work.  It has a lot of spaces

Comment: Is there another way or how can i take out the spaces?

Comment: Add, '-encoding ASCII'  after the -append.  the file your're editing apparently expects unicode.

Comment: I think you mean this and it worked.
ls "~\desktop\CMR Desktop.rdp" | %{ "set audioqualitymode:1:2" | Out-File $_.FullName -append -encoding ASCII}
Awesome TNX